# inconsistent and intansparent error when codesigning

Tags: ios, gluon, gluon-mobile, javafxports

I am using version 2.0.28 of jfxmobile-plugin and my setup works for simple applications. When I start adding more dependencies the code signing step starts failing **'most of the time'**.

For the same project with the same gradle file signing sometimes works and many times it does not.

Signing works…

```
[14:18:39:552] BosonAppSupport: Signing app with identity: SigningIdentity [name=iPhone Developer: Joerg Wille (**********), fingerprint=A71D4119E0DD7F4B8465E5B5C3F3B508D2C57E61] 
[14:18:49:570] BosonAppSupport: RES for signing = false 
[14:18:53:952] BosonAppSupport: Validating codesign... 
[SUB] /Users/joerg/Documents/EclipseWorkspaces/TanMobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp/build/gvm/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp.app: valid on disk
[SUB] /Users/joerg/Documents/EclipseWorkspaces/TanMobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp/build/gvm/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
[14:18:55:489] BosonAppSupport: RES for validateCodesign = true 
[14:18:55:489] BosonAppSupport: Validation codesign result: true 
[14:18:55:489] BosonAppSupport: Codesign done
```

Compiling a 2’nd time without any changes, signing fails!

```
[14:23:09:672] BosonAppSupport: Signing app with identity: SigningIdentity [name=iPhone Developer: Joerg Wille (**********), fingerprint=A71D4119E0DD7F4B8465E5B5C3F3B508D2C57E61] 
[14:23:19:684] BosonAppSupport: RES for signing = false 
[14:23:20:475] BosonAppSupport: Validating codesign... 
[SUB] /Users/joerg/Documents/EclipseWorkspaces/TanMobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp/build/gvm/com.dad.software.tan.mpa1.mobile.uiapp.app: code object is not signed at all
[SUB] In architecture: arm64
[14:23:20:498] BosonAppSupport: RES for validateCodesign = true 
[14:23:20:498] BosonAppSupport: Validation codesign result: false 
[14:23:20:498] BosonAppSupport: Codesign validation failed 
[14:23:20:499] BosonAppBuilder: prepare Install failed 
[14:23:20:499] BosonAppBuilder: Something went wrong. App wasn't installed on the device
```

1. most obvious the problem has to do with the kind of added compile-dependencies and their transient dependencies. When adding dependencies, what are potential problems?
2. what changes in project or in the setup can influence code signing to be not working anymore (e.g. undeleted temp files, number of compile-dependencies or size of project or changes to the forceLinkClasses)?
3. how can log-level for code-signing be made more verbose?
4. how likely is this a problem of the current versions of jfxmobile-plugin or gvmbuilder?

Comment: If you run `./gradlew clean launchIOSDevice` several times, does code signing fail? The log starting with `[SUB]` is the direct output of the Xcode `codesign` tool, that uses verbose options already.